# Is there a way to instantiate a new instance of a subclass from inside a super class method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to be able to instantiate a new instance of a subclass from inside a superclass method.

If I have just a single class with no inheritance, it is straight forward:

```
class A {
    static build(opts) {
        return new A(opts)
    }   
    makeAnother() {
        return A.build(...)
    }
}

const a = new A()
const a2 = a.makeAnother()
```

This works.  However, it doesn't work with subclassing:

```
class B extends A { ... }

const b = new B()
const b2 = b.makeAnother() // this returns an instance of A, not B
```

I suppose I could add the build & makeAnother methods to each subclass, but I would rather not repeat things.

Comment: Do you want B's `makeAnother` to return a new `B` object? If so, then I think the only way to do that is to repeat yourself

Comment: Yeah, to return a new B object -- I'll clarify the post

Comment: Why do you need the `build()` method when you can just call the constructor directly?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `this.constructor` inside the super class to get to the constructor of the subclass (or the super class itself, if the method is called on a super instance rather than a sub instance):

```js
class A {
    static build(theClass) {
        return new theClass()
    }   
    makeAnother() {
        return A.build(this.constructor)
    }
}

const a = new A()
const a2 = a.makeAnother()
console.log(a2 instanceof A);

class B extends A { }

const b = new B()
const b2 = b.makeAnother()
console.log(b2 instanceof B);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `static build(theClass, opts)`?

Comment: If an argument needs to be passed along, sure, but it wasn't being passed or used in OP's code

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use

```
class A {
    static build(opts) {
        return new this(opts)
    }   
    makeAnother() {
        return this.constructor.build(...)
    }
}
```

Unless `build` does more than shown here, you don't need it at all of course, you'd rather directly `return new this.constructor(...)` in `makeAnother`.