# Typescript/Javascript Circular dependency: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, typescript, circular-dependency, factory-pattern

### Question

Hello,
the following code example throws the error:

```
TypeError: Super constructor null of SecondChild is not a constructor
    at new SecondChild (<anonymous>:8:19)
    at <anonymous>:49:13
    at dn (<anonymous>:16:5449)
```

Currently i am trying to understand what exactly the issue is about and how to implement the factory pattern in typescript/javascript. There are several behaviours which i don´t quite understand:

1. If I remove the second-child of the code everything works fine except if I swap the order of the export statements in the index.ts file of the **child** and **parent** export.
2. If I combine the files child.ts and second-child.ts into one single file which defines both classes the exception is also gone

- **Is the error linked to the circular dependencies? And if so, what exactly is the problem behind circular dependencies in typescript/javascript?**
- **Can someone explain the behaviour of the code example to me?**

It would be possible to prevent the error if i implemented the parent class without using the type "this" in combination with the factory Method but it seems pretty convenient. The goal behind the abstracted method duplicate is that it returns a subclass instance. I could implement it in every subclass but in my real world project the complexity is much higher.

### Project structure:

```
src/
  child.ts
  factory.ts
  index.ts
  parent.ts
  main.ts
  second-child.ts
```

### File Content

#### main.ts:

```ts
// Throws error
import { Child, Parent, SecondChild  } from './index'


console.log(new Child().duplicate())
console.log(new SecondChild().duplicate())
console.log(new Parent().duplicate())

// Works as intended:
// import { Child, Parent} from './index'


// console.log(new Child().duplicate())
// console.log(new Parent().duplicate())
```

#### parent.ts

```ts
import { factory } from './factory'

export class Parent {
  isChild = 0;
  duplicate(): this {
    return factory(this.isChild) as unknown as this;
  }
}
```

#### child.ts

```ts
import {Parent} from './parent'

export class Child extends Parent{
  override isChild = 1;
}
```

#### second-child.ts

```ts
import {Parent} from './parent'

export class SecondChild extends Parent{
  override isChild = 2;
}
```

#### factory.ts

```ts
import { Child } from './child'
import { SecondChild } from './second-child'
import { Parent } from './parent'

export function factory(child: number):Child;
export function factory(...args: unknown[]):Parent {
  switch (args[0]) {
    case 1: {
      return new Child()
    }
    case 2:  {
      return new SecondChild()
    }
    default: {
      return new Parent();
    }
  }
}
```

#### index.ts

```ts
export * from './child'
export * from './second-child'
export * from './parent'
export * from './factory'
```

### Project Description

- Entry point: main.ts
- index.ts exports the content of **child.ts, factory.ts, parent.ts, second-child.ts**

[example Playground](https://playcode.io/1299785)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Circular dependencies between modules are a complex beast. The order of evaluation depends on the order of the `import` statements and the entry point, which is very fragile. JS runs the code in a module after its dependencies are met, doing a DFS graph traversal, but it has to ignore dependencies that were already visited and are still waiting for evaluation of their dependencies.

In your case, that means

- *main.ts* imports *index.ts*

  - *index.ts* imports *child.ts*

    - *child.ts* imports *parent.ts*

      - *parent.ts* imports *factory.ts*

        - *factory.ts* imports *child.ts*, but it won't wait for its evaluation (we're already trying to evaluate it)
        - *factory.ts* imports *second-child.ts*

          - *second-child.ts* imports *parent.ts*, but it won't wait for its evaluation (we're already trying to evaluate it)
          - *second-child.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated. The `Parent` variable is already set up but [still not initialised](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33198849/1048572), throwing an exception.

In your case, you can fix this by changing the imports in *factory.ts* to

```
import { Child, SecondChild, Parent } from './index';
```

Now, the traversal looks as follows:

- *main.ts* imports *index.ts*

  - *index.ts* imports *child.ts*

    - *child.ts* imports *parent.ts*

      - *parent.ts* imports *factory.ts*

        - *factory.ts* imports *index.ts*, but it won't wait for its evaluation (we're already trying to evaluate it)
        - *factory.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated. It declares the `factory` function, which - since it is not immediately called - does not attempt to access the uninitialised imported variables
      - *parent.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated and initialises `Parent`.
    - *child.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated and initialises `Child` (given `Parent` is already initialised)
  - *index.ts* imports *second-child.ts*

    - *second-child.ts* imports *parent.ts*, which already is evaluated
    - *second-child.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated and initialises `SecondChild`
  - *index.ts* imports *parent.ts*, which is already evaluated
  - *index.ts* imports *factory.ts*, which is already evaluated
  - *index.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated (which is empty and does nothing)
- *main.ts* has no remaining imports, so its code is evaluated which creates a few instances and calls their methods which call the `factory()` function, whose imports are now initialised

A tool like [`dpdm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dpdm) will help you understand this even for large dependency graphs. And it'll urge you to avoid the circular dependencies, they're more trouble than they're worth, if you can easily avoid them.

In your case I would recommend to implement `duplicate` without `factory` but rather by conventional cloning (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64508867/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68518844/1048572)), or to implement `factory` by using a class registry that the classes can register themselves with instead of importing them all into *factory.ts*.

Comment: Very good and detailed explanation!

Comment: Thank you! For your detailed explanation and advise. Now I understand the problem and was able to fix it. I will look into the topic conventional cloning and post an alternative solution in this thread.